# Get a certain value from a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object

eg

```
{
 "href":"Test",
 "commentID":"12334556778"
}
```

Is there a way just to get the second line i.e. "commentID":"12334556778"
I'm using

```
JSON.stringify(json)
```

Thanks all

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. `JSON.stringify` is for serializing JavaScript objects into JSON. The "JSON object" you posted, is it the result of this operation? Otherwise I cannot see how these two are related. It is unclear whether you are receiving JSON or creating JSON.  But in any case, you probably have to work with JavaScript objects, so JSON does not seem to be relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` accepts a third argument which handles white-space in the output.  If the third argument is present and "truthy", line-breaks will be inserted and each level will be indented using the argument's string value, or a number of spaces if a number is passed.  Using this technique, you can get the browser to insert line-breaks and then split on those line-breaks in the result:

```
var obj = {
        "href":"Test",
        "commentID":"12334556778"
    },
    arr = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1).split("\n");

alert(arr[2]);
//-> ' "commentID": "12334556778"'
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/ercRS/** (requires browsers with JSON/trim)

You might want to trim any leading white space or trailing comma, but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another object containing only the `commentID` property:

```
var obj = {
    "href": "Test",
    "commentID": "12334556778"
};

var result = JSON.stringify({
    "commentID": obj.commentID
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a JSON object at hand, just use it like you would use an array.

```
var jsonObject = {
   "href":"Test",
   "commentID":"12334556778"
}
alert(jsonObject['commentID']); // alerts 123445678
```

JSON.stringify() is used if you want to send the data back to your server.

Comment: That's not a JSON object. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: Since JSON is short for **JavaScript Object Notation** I doubt that.

Comment: *Java* is also in *JavaScript* but they are not related in any way. JSON is a data format with a syntax similar to JavaScript object literals. A JavaScript object is a data type in JavaScript. You cannot mix that terminology.

Comment: @Felix is correct.  JSON is a data transfer format.  There's no such thing as a "JSON object", JSON can only be a string.

Comment: The convenience in using JSON is exactly the opposite of your comment.  While Java and JavaScript have similar names due to marketing ideas, JSON and JavaScript share a foundation like XHTML and XML.

Comment: Maybe, but it does not make you right ;) Another example: If you say that `jsonObject` contains JSON, then I should be able to parse it with `JSON.parse` right? But that's not possible. Another analogy might be this: `var csv = "a", "b", "c"` is valid JavaScript but no one would say that it is CSV (although it looks similar). My point: Only because it looks the same does not make it the same.

Comment: I get your point, and of course I admit that one can point this out. But the basis of JSON syntax is JavaScript, even the name contains JavaScript, it really is just a subset of JavaScript notation and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still, mixing the names is a common mistake which can lead to a lot of confusion. I honestly think Crockford should have chosen another name....

Comment: My perspective on this is slightly different, assuming JSON and JS are in no way interchangeable leads often to very intricate constructs beginners write, just because nobody told them that it is absolutely ok to not write var myServerData = JSON.parse('{"test": "text"}'); wich in many cases leads to parsing errors along the way.

Comment: The example doesn't work because object keys are case-sensitive (commentID vs commentId)